# clone display laptop/tv

Tags: display

I am "old fart" and my vision is not too good. I am using Linux Mint 17.3 KDE, where the clone display works. I installed this oS and the "clone" do not work.
My laptop is Lenovo G51. Any way to fix this?. Thanks.

Comment: We would need more information on what you tried and what exactly you were expecting to do

Comment: Are you just looking for the "Mirror Displays" switch in the "Displays" plug?